# Why I cannot use text align?

Tags: vertical-alignment, text-align

I cannot move the navigation links to the right. I also want to vertically center them with the logo.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/kfp1d034/ `

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
```

```
<div class="home">

  <div class="navBar">


    <div class="logo">

      <a href="#">

        <img src="https://cdn.logo.com/hotlink-ok/logo-social.png" alt="logo">

      </a>

    </div>


    <div class="navPages">

      <div class="navLinks">

        <a href="#">

          Home

        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="navLinks">

        <a href="#">

          About

        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="navLinks">

        <a href="#">

          Our Offers

        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="navLinks">

        <a href="#">

          Gallery

        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="navLinks">

        <a href="#">

          Blog

        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="navLinks">

        <a href="#">

          Contact

        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

```
body {

background-color: aqua;
```

}

.logo {

```
width: fit-content;

display: inline-block;
```

}

.logo img {

```
width: 100px;
```

}

.navPages {

```
width: fit-content;

display: inline-block;
```

}

.navLinks {

```
display: inline-block;
```

border-top: 2px solid #8f7854;

}

.navLinks a{

```
text-decoration: none;

color: white;
  
}
```

I tried to use text-align and it does not work.

HTML and CSS code are provided above.

Answer (score 1):

What it is usually made is the following.

Assuming you are doing this in the navbar:

```
navbar {
   display: flex;
   align-content: space-between;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

This will only work if you have 2 different elements (for example, a div for the logo and a div for the links).

EDIT: since I answered your question before you edited it, your CSS has to look like this:

```
.navBar {
       display: flex;
       align-content: space-between;
       justify-content: center;
    }
```

EDIT2:
[Example 1](https://acncuc.medium.com/a-simple-css-horizontal-navigation-bar-using-inline-block-c507c581db69)
[Example 2](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_nav)

Comment: Thank you. I am studying a course, and, in this assignment, I must use limited options to do this task. It is required to use display: inline-block

Comment: I will never understand why schools do that, Flexbox and CSSGrid are the standard today, avoiding them is just wrong. I will update my answer with two links I think they will help you